# SFML how to make various shapes move in random directions?

Tags: c++, codeblocks, sfml, shapes

I am having troubles in making shapes moving in random directions, with the code that i currently have they all move in the same direction and then change to another direction randomly.

Here is the code

```
for(int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
    {
        int randomMoveX = rand() % 2 + (-1);
        int randomMoveY = rand() % 2 + (-1);
        circleObjectArray[i].move(randomMoveX,randomMoveY);
        while(randomMoveX == 0)
        {
            randomMoveX = rand() % 2 + (-1);
        }
        while(randomMoveY == 0)
        {
            randomMoveY = rand() % 2 + (-1);
        }

        cout << "randomMoveX: " << randomMoveX << endl;
        cout << "randomMoveY: " << randomMoveY << endl;
    }
```

How can i change my code to be able to do move them in random directions individually?

Thank you for your time :D

Comment: `while(randomMoveX == 0)
        {
            randomMoveX = rand() % 2 + (-1);` is a bit silly, since the assignment can only ever produce 2 values (one of them being 0). So why have a loop? If the value is currently 0 you clearly want the other one, so after the loop the value will always be the non-0 value, so why not just assign that and get rid of the loop.

Comment: Oh i thought with randomMoveX = rand() % 2 + (-1); i could get a random value between 1 and -1

Comment: Why would you think that? `rand() % 2` gives only 0 or 1 and adding a constant to that doesn't change the fact that the end result can only ever be one of two different values. Like, if you add 42 it'll only ever be `42` or `43`.

Comment: So if i want to have a rand() between -1 and 1 i need to do rand % 3 + (-1)?

Comment: Personally I would never use `rand` in modern C++. I'd use the modern facilities available in [<random>](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) and to get a number in a specific range I'd use [std::uniform_int_distribution](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution). Trying to generate a distribution with `%` is a really bad idea since it introduces bias in your numbers unless your divisor divides the available range of your generator exactly.

Comment: I recommended watching this talk: [rand() Considered Harmful](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/rand-Considered-Harmful)

Comment: Thank you so much for all the information you have given me :D , i was able to make a random generator that works :)

Comment: How is this related to SFML ?

Answer (score 1):

When you run your app, a seed is set for random as `srand(1)`.

To use different value in rand you need to change the seed of random.
Then use the function [srand](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/srand) and save it in a `unsigned int` to use different rand for different shape.